# Not able to import image id

Tags: android, kotlin

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1OoZU.png)

Glide.with(this).load(url).into(imageView)

Comment: synthetic imports have been deprecated and removed, use findViewById/viewbinding

Comment: What is the `id` of your `ImageView`?

Comment: id of the image is imageView

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `findViewById`:

```
Glide.with(this).load(url).into(findViewById(R.id.imageView))
```

However, the best approach would be using `viewBinding`:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        ...

        Glide.with(this).load(url).into(binding.imageView)
    }
}
```

In this case, don't forget to enable `viewBinding` in your app-level `build.gradle` file, by adding:

```
android {
    ...
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
    }
}
```

For more on `viewBinding` check [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding)